# Check whether the given value is in the binary search tree

Tags: python

This is the code I was given and I need to make changes to it. The function looks for the value in the given BST and returns True if target is in the tree. Here's the code:

```
def member_prim(tnode, target):
    """
    Purpose:
        Check if target is stored in the binary search tree.
    Pre-Conditions:
        :param tnode: a treenode with the BST property
        :param target: a value
    Post-Conditions:
        none
    Return
        :return: True if target is in the tree
    """

    if tnode is None:
        return False
    elif target < tnode.data:
        right = tnode.right
        return member_prim(right, target)
    else:
        tnode.right = tnode.left
        return member_prim(tnode.right, target)
```

I made few changes to the code and here's what I did:

```
if tnode is None:
    return False
elif tnode.data is not target:
    return False
elif target > tnode.data:
    right = tnode.right
    return member_prim(right, target)
else:
    tnode.right = tnode.left
    return member_prim(tnode.right, target)
```

Still it throws Attribute Error, saying object 'treenode' has no attribute 'data'.

Here's treenode class:

```
class treenode(object):

    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        """
        Purpose:
            Create a new treenode for the given data.
        Pre-conditions:
            data:  Any data value to be stored in the treenode
            left, right:  Another treenode (or None, by default)
        Post-condition:
            none
        """
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

Please let me know where I went wrong and how can I fix it.

Comment: Please combine your code into one piece that also includes the actual construction of an example tree, and the *call* of `member_prim` that triggers the error.

Comment: If ```target < tnode.data```, shouldn't you be checking in the left sub tree ? Why are you checking in the right sub tree ```member_prim(right, target)``` ?

Comment: `tnode.right = ...`: why would that function *mutate* the tree? It is supposed to only traverse it, not change it, right? The code that "was given" you, is already wrong. Why not look up correct code from a reliable source? For instance, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Searching)

Answer (score -1):

```
class treenode(object):

def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
    """
    Purpose:
        Create a new treenode for the given data.
    Pre-conditions:
        data:  Any data value to be stored in the treenode
        left, right:  Another treenode (or None, by default)
    Post-condition:
        none
    """
    self.data = data
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

def trav(root, target):
    if not root:
        return False
    if root.data == target:
        return True
    if root.data > target:
        return trav(root.left, target)
    if root.data < target:
        return trav(root.right, target)
```

This code will find you the if the target value is present or not.